# JEditorpane load css image through classloader

Tags: java, image, swing, classloader, jeditorpane

I am packaging my app as a runnable jar with all my images in it. For my JEditorPane, how can I write the css file/url for 'background' property as I will not be able to get the path since the image is packaged in jar?

If I load the image through class loader getResourceAsStream, how can I refer it in JEditorPane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://java-sl.com/tip_local_images.html Use this